# Restrict numbers 1-10 in textInput Box in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

I have a TextInput box. I have to restrict a  range more than 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 numbers only in the text Box.If i enter any number above that it should be allowed. If enter 11 or more than that, it should not allow to enter. it should allow from 1- 10 digits in the text box.
If enter 11 or 0 it should not allow and more than 10 should not allowed.

Please help me how to restrict it in TextInput Box in Flex. If any one knows about thte regular expression, please help me out .

Comment: is it working the solution I wrote you?

Comment: not working. i cannot enter even any number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only thing that the user can input are numbers 1 to 10,
 
try using the `NumericStepper` component instead.

This component has the features you describe built in.

For example:

```
<s:NumericStepper minimum="1" maximum="10" value="0" stepSize="1" maxChars="10"/>
```

Where:

- **minimum** is the minimum allowed value
- **maximum** is the maximum allowed value
- **value** is the initial value
- **maxChars** is the amount of characters allowed
- **stepsize** is the amount by which the amount can be increased or decreased with the arrow buttons

Check out the livedocs:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/NumericStepper.html
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/NumericStepper.html

Cheers

Comment: +1 for a good alternative.  It doesn't answer the question, but it may be what the original poster needs.

Comment: But it is asking default value. how to give default value in this stepper

Comment: Edited my post to answer your comment

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict the characters entered into a TextInput using the [restrict](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#restrict) property.  If you only want to allow numbers entered, you can do this:

```
<s:TextInput restrict="0-9" />
```

You can restrict the total number of characters entered into the TextInput using the [maxChars property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#maxChars).

```
<s:TextInput maxChars="10" />
```

There is no reason they can't be combined

```
<s:TextInput maxChars="10" restrict="0-9" />
```

If you're only accepting numeric input, you could also use a [NumericStepper](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/NumericStepper.html) component.

```
<s:NumericStepper maximum="1" maximum="9999999999" />
```

I'm not sure if there is an upper limit on NumericSteppers.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: maxchar type is `maxChars:int` can we give it in a range `"0-9"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mx:TextInput` because it has `textInput` event

```
<mx:TextInput id="ti" restrict="0-9" textInput="Myfun(event)"/>
```

then your `Myfun` will be:

```
private function Myfun(ev:TextEvent):void
        {
            if(Number(ti.text + ev.text)>10)
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
```

This will not allow you to type numbers greater than 10

if you want 10 digits use..

```
<s:TextInput maxChars="10" restrict="0-9" />
```

Comment: @Ravi K Chowdary Did you use `mx:TextInput`? above code should run perfectly.. did you tried it? what is not working?

Comment: I used s:TextInput. This textInput field is not available in flex4.